# Vue-apollo. Queries don't work return 400 Bad Request

Tags: django, vue.js, vue-apollo

I am building a frontend with Vue cli and backend with Django with Graphene. The mutation works fine but not the queries.

When I run the same query from GraphiQL, works fine.

**Frontend**

- @vue/cli 4.1.2
- vue-apollo 3.0.2

**Backend**

- python 3.8
- django 3.0.2
- graphene-django 2.8.0
- django-graphql-jwt 0.3.0

*queries.js*

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const ME_QUERY = gql`
    query me { 
        me {
            username
            is_active
        }
    }
`
```

*Home.vue*

```
<script>
import { ME_QUERY } from '@/graphql/queries'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  async mounted () {
    await this.$apollo
      .query({
        query: ME_QUERY
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      })
      .catch(({ graphQLErrors }) => {
        graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) => console.log(`Error Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`))
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

*schema.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, get_user_model
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
import graphql_jwt
from graphql_jwt.decorators import jwt_cookie

class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

class ObtainJSONWebToken(graphql_jwt.JSONWebTokenMutation):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    @classmethod
    def resolve(cls, root, info, **kwargs):
        return cls(user=info.context.user)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    me = graphene.Field(UserType)

    def resolve_me(root, info):
        user = info.context.user
        if user.is_anonymous:
            raise Exception('Authentication failure!!')
        return user


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    # token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
    refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()
    revoke_token = graphql_jwt.Revoke.Field()
    log_in = ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

after to install the extension Graphql in Firefox and found my mistake.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"is_active\" on type \"UserType\". Did you mean \"isActive\"?",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Changing to `isActive` the query worked fine.